# Short story about Grandma showing her granddaughter how to fix a robotic toaster

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Many years ago, I read a charming sci fi short story in an anthology. I'm trying to find it again.

Grandma lived in a highrise apartment. Her granddaughter arrived the day Grandma was to receive her newest annual robotic toaster that did much more. It arrived. Grandma waited until it broke, so she could repair it back into just a simple toaster.

Does anyone remember this old man's (my) memory of dealing with new fangled technology?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: Smart toasters are dumb; https://blog.reedsy.com/short-story/7psp98/

Comment: https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2020/01/unauthorized-bread-a-near-future-tale-of-refugees-and-sinister-iot-appliances/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is "[The Toaster](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63776)" by Piers Anthony published in the anthology collection *Anthonology*.

I remember it being pretty striking.  Been literal decades but as I recall it essentially predicts smart phones, or rather a ubiquitous uber device that he just happens to pick the toaster as the avatar for for comedic effect, and the old woman isn't really "fixing" the toaster but essentially jail breaking it as a form of protest to the world she lives in.  She's almost immediately taken awaken by door kicking agents of the government after she restores the toaster into a device that heats bread.  A result she's expecting to happen.

> Miss Porter laughed as she nonchalantly discarded the spent disrupter. "You are mistaken, dear. Stripped of its modernistic, male-inspired notions, it will have to revert to the limited functions of its ancestry. In short, it will MAKE TOAST."
>
> "Yess Misstresss," the machine slurred dutifully. It retreated into itself for a few minutes of internal clicks and gurgles. Evidently something quite complicated was going on inside. At length, a slot opened and a plate emerged containing two pieces of hotly buttered toast.
>
> "That's very good, Tribune," Miss Porter said, patting the machine on its lobotomized dome.
>
> "Thank you, Misstresss," it replied slavishly.
>
> Miss Porter took the plate and handed one of the pieces to her niece. "This, my dear, is toast. Eat it."
>
> Ophelia took it and bit in doubtfully.
>
> Suddenly her face lighted. "Auntie!" she exclaimed incredulously.  "It's GOOD!"

But I was an elementary school kid when I encountered it so my memory might be hazy.  I've wanted to reread it for ages, it clearly struck a chord in child me, but I could never find a copy of the collection.

Comment: From [a review](https://jamesdavisnicoll.com/review/those-little-eyes): "What might have put editors off way back in the 1960s is the way the story dwells on the precocious ten-year-old’s thigh-revealing clothing." Oh, Piers Anthony...

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any government agents, just a brainfried toaster and some hot buttered toast.  But it is a good match for the question.  And the aspect of the niece showing up for the arrival of the new toaster makes this likely the correct answer.

Comment: Anthonology by Piers Anthony is it!! Thank you. It's a cute story.

Comment: Quote verified against the archive.org [copy of *Anthonology*](https://archive.org/details/anthonology00anth/page/20/mode/2up).

Comment: @KenRich - if this is the correct answer, as you say in your comment, please *accept* it by clicking the checkmark below the voting buttons.